# User Control is not updating in window (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml

There is a UserControl which contains the bindings like below.

```
<TextBox Margin="5" Padding="0" IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsTabStop="False" FontSize="{DynamicResource TitleFontSize}" Text="{Binding ErrorTitle, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

it is bound by stack panel with name of GenericErrorControl and binding is as

```
<Visibility="{Binding IsShown, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
```

Above control is added to one of view as below.

```
<views:GenericErrorControl Grid.Row="8"  DataContext="{Binding GenericErrorControl, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top/>
```

The problem is that user control is not appearing in the window after. In my viewmodel creating object i'm setting the value of IsShown but its not appearing. Kindly help and let me know if any other details needed.

Comment: this is not very clear. After what? Could you provide the whole xaml?

Comment: Please share xaml and code behind, so that we can assist you.

Comment: the game is called guess the xaml... ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the binding is failing ie the fallback value is used from above code.

**Things to do :**

1. Ensure that your ViewModel inherits from the base class BindableBase ie it somehow implements the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface and on property change, the **PropertyChanged** event is fired.
2. ie You have something similar to this in your view model.

   private bool _IsShown;
   public bool IsShown
   {
      get { return _IsShown; }
      set { SetProperty(ref _IsShown, value); } 
   }
3. Double check your converter or post code here.